# Remove Link From Quick Launch Navigation Heading

Tags: 2016, quick-launch

Is it possible to to use quick launch headings as categories that aren't themselves links? I don't want the headings to be clickable.

I've tried setting the web address to blank, `javascript: return true;`, etc. but SharePoint's pretty strict about it being a "valid" url.

The Recent heading does this, but I have a feeling it's a special kind of heading.

My best bet seems to be stripping out the links with some js in the masterpage, but that seems a bit hacky.

Is there a better way?

Comment: do you  mean you want to add new headings to quicklaunch like Recent?

Comment: Only like Recent in the sense that they're not clickable. But otherwise completely standard headings. Headings that aren't clickable.

Comment: Have this changed since SharePoint 2013 where you just could add a title and no url to act as a header?

Comment: Yup. In SharePoint 2016, if you don't include a url, it'll save it with "/" instead of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure site collection feature. Then you can edit the quick launch by navigating to Site Settings -> Navigation (under Look and Feel).

That interface permits you to add headings which are not links.